# Prevent Apache2 from executing CGI in Static Directory

Tags: apache2, cgi, static-content

I am running an Apache 2 web server running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I have a Python CGI handler enabled for the `/var/www/html` directory, which is the `DocumentRoot`. I am wondering how to exclude a certain directory from running CGI for Python files.
Here in my CGI config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.py -f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.py
        </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/static/cdn">
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        Options +Indexes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the `/static/cdn` directory, I want `.py` files to be served just like any other static file, instead of being executed as CGI. Here is a tree of the `cdn` directory:

```
.
├── checkForUpdates.exe
├── checkForUpdates.py
└── findLogErrors
    ├── botCriteria.json
    ├── cleanup.json
    ├── findLogErrors.exe
    └── version.json

1 directory, 6 files
```

I am able to [see the indexes of the directory in the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzQOz.png), as desired. I am able to view or download any file from this directory except `checkForUpdates.py`. The server is not trying to execute it as CGI, it's giving a 403. The permissions on `checkForUpdates.py` are the same as the other files:

```
nbroyles@webserver:/var/www/html/static/cdn$ ls -altr
total 15548
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data web 15901526 Nov 17 11:37 checkForUpdates.exe
drwxrwxr-x 7 www-data web     4096 Nov 19 11:13 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data web     4096 Dec 23 09:41 findLogErrors
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data web     4096 Dec 23 09:49 .
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data web     2072 Dec 23 09:49 checkForUpdates.py
```

How can I view the `.py` file just like any of the `.json` or `.exe` files? I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing in my config. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `SetHandler default-handler` in `<Directory "/var/www/html/static/cdn">`

Comment: That works to display the Python file, but now the indexes are not showing.

Comment: Then chage it to `SetHandler default-handler .py`

Comment: `apachectl configtest` shows `SetHandler takes one argument, a handler name that overrides any other configured handler`, but I changed it to `AddHandler` and it's all good. Thank you!